# Layout view crashing ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3

I'm using ArcMap 10.3.1 from a basic desktop concurrent use license. The problem I'm experiencing occurs when I load an existing mxd (creating using 10.3.1), and then try to switch from data view to layout view. When I try to switch views, the program crashes. I have tried to delete the normal.mxt file and this has not solved the problem. I've also updated my video driver and run the ERSI diagnostic to see if my computer is capable of running the program. I've also run a diagnostic to ensure that my computer is not experiencing any issue with memory or drivers. 
Any ideas on what might be causing the problem or how to fix it?

Comment: Is it just one particular MXD that causes the crash?

Comment: I have had problems like this in the past. It was as a result of carrying forward old versions of mxd (e.g. arcmap 9.3, 10, etc). I found the quickest solution was to open a new MXD in 10.3.1 and copy the content from the layers list into the new (10.3.1) MXD.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried to create a new file, add the layers, and it hasn't worked. Additionally, the mxd was created in 10.3.1 so there shouldn't be an problem from using older versions. It's not just one mxd either, its all of them on my C: and my network drives that have this problem.

Comment: You might also want to investigate the video card(s) that are being used on the machine

Comment: We are having the same issue. ArcGIS shuts down when in map layout view. We have created multiple new .mxd templates from scratch and that does not fix the problem. I'm about to run the MXD Doctor and defragmenter to see if that will solve the issue. Any other recommendations would be great! Thanks! -Lindsey

Answer (score 1):

Copy over the content to new version because some may be backlogged in old versions.

Also try using save a copy for that file.

Relative pathnames may have something to do with finding files.

Answer (score 1):

Try running MXD Doctor
"C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.3\Tools\MXDDoctor.exe"

or

ArcGIS Document Defragmenter
"C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.3\Tools\DocDefragmenter.exe"

I have had the most luck Nkronck's answer.  MXD files may become unstable over time and refreshing it by creating a new one is usually the quickest solution, however not always the case.